# Draw shadow beyond c lipped region on Iphone

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

In a UIView, is it possible to draw a drop shadow beyond a clip path? I tried to use CGContextSetShadow() before clipping and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It's the drawing, not setting the shadow, that actually *draws* shadows. All drawing is clipped to the clip path.

Make your clip bounds bigger.